# Rubymine warns header partial HTML with "element table is not close"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I have view files like these:

### comments/_comment.html.erb

```
<tr>
  <td><%= comment.author %></td>
  <td><%= comment.text %></td>
</tr>
```

### comments/_table_header.html.erb

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Author</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
```

### comments/_table_footer.html.erb

```
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then I got warning "element table is not close" by RubyMine.

Is there a better way to write table this?
If there is not, is there a way to suppress the warning only when the file name includes `_header` or `_footer`?

I want keep active this warning itself for other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `_table.html.erb` partial and don't split it up into header and footer.

**comments/_table.html.erb**

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Author</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%= render @comments %> <!-- Rails magic here! -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**comments/_comment.html.erb**

```
<tr>
  <td><%= comment.author %></td>
  <td><%= comment.text %></td>
</tr>
```